# Using pickle to serialize a class object

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I am using pickle to serialise a class object like the following

object = constructor()
pickle_string = pickle.dump(object)

and then I want to reconstruct the object from pickle_string. I tried

pickle.load(pickle_string)

it does not seem to work any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For writing into strings you should use [`pickle.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). There are two families of functions in [this module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html): `loads` and `dumps` do stuff with strings, and `load` and `dump` do stuff on *streams*.

Incidentally, `pickle` is quite dated. You might consider, at the very least, [`cPickle`](http://pymotw.com/2/pickle/), which is much faster.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Sometime one 's' :D and yes shifted to cPickle.